# Php PDO connection issue

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am using the following php code to connect to a remote database:

```
    <?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set( 'display_errors','1');

      $db_host = "host"; 
      $db_user = "user"; 
      $db_pass = "pass"; 
      $db_name = "name"; 

      try{
        $dbc = new PDO("mysql:dbname=$db_name;host=$db_host",$db_user,$db_pass);
      }

       catch(PDOException $e){
          echo '<p>There was a problem with your connection: '.$e->getMessage().'</p>';

      }

      $query = "some query";
      $results = $dbc->query($query);

      $row = $results->rowCount();




?>
```

But it keeps generating the following error message:

```
Warning: PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in /example.php on line 11

There was a problem with your connection: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

//shouldn't this error below not even show because the try never completes?

Notice: Undefined variable: dbc in /example.php on line 25

Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in /example.php on line 25
```

Comment: Have you tried to search solution of similar problem?

Comment: $db_host = "host"; 
      $db_user = "user"; 
      $db_pass = "pass"; 
      $db_name = "name"; 
Are you subsituting the actual values ? I think its unable to resolve the host

Comment: yes I have searched, and none of them provide an answer that will cure my problem. @lucky, yes I substitute the real and proper values.

Comment: is there an sql server running on your targeted host?

Comment: I have setup the mysql database and whitelisted the remote address for the user if that helps.

Comment: It's obvious, it can't resolve the IP address for your host name

Comment: Okay, so what does that mean and what action do I take to solve it?

Comment: What port is your DB listening on?

Comment: I don't know. How do I find that out through a typical host control panel? Or can I find that out in phpmyadmin?

Comment: Either your hostname is invalid, or [less likely] DNS resolution is broken on the server. Double check your hostname, and if that doesn't fix it then contact your hosting provider.

Comment: my host has ultimately been of no help. Further, when I try to connect using mysql or mysqli, it just goes on and on until it times out.

Comment: I'm having issues with a NetworkManager/DNSmasq setup. My hostname is defined in my /etc/hosts file. I'm running Fedora 21. Switching the address to an IP address works flawlessly. I've checked the permissions and made rules for ::1, localhost and 127.0.0.1. I'm thinking it's some strangeness with PDO, as it always works when using the mysql-client. I'm also using mariadb 10.0.21